# RxJS - Combine Two HTTP GET Parallel Requests

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need advice. I'm quite new to RxJS so I want to use it correctly.
I need to get two different arrays from API. I want to finish this operation only when both of them are complete because I need to send them to the child component (The child component has two different list boxes which depend on each other).

I want to store these Observables in:

```
departments$: Observable<IDepartment[]>;
workers$: Observable<IWorker[]>;
```

Solution for this problem:

```
  departments$ = this.http.get<string[]>('api/departments')
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );

  workers$ = this.http.get<string[]>('api/workers')
    .pipe(
      tap(data => JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );

  departmentsAndWorkers$ = forkJoin({
    departments$: this.departments$,
    workers$: this.workers$
  })
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using forkJoin like this :

```
forkJoin([departments$,workers$]).subscribe((resp: any) => { 
   // resp[0] : departments$
   // resp[1] : workers$
  },
  errors=>{
 }
});
```

Comment: I've edited the question, can you please take a look and tell me if the implementation is correct?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `forkJoin` RxJS operator. It will emit a tuple value when all the requests are completed. Read more about it: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Comment: in addition to this I would suggest you test the operator decision tree, its very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use forkJoin: Wait for Observables to complete and then combine last values they emitted; complete immediately if an empty array is passed.
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

or combineLatest: Whenever any input Observable emits a value, it computes a formula using the latest values from all the inputs, then emits the output of that formula.
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest